# pandas automatically converting timestamp columns when i query using timestamp columns? how can i get the same data as it is in the postgres db?

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql

This is the query which i used in  postgres(pgadmin)

`select start_time,fw_job_id from dish_swife_tracker WHERE date(start_time) = '2022-07-21'`

when i use this query Im getting this output This is the correct output

**output 1: 2022-07-21 00:31:36.783 +0530, 6120c464-085e-11ed-80b2-0242ac120002**

but when i run the same query in my python script using pandas read_sql_query Im getting a different time format...Can someone please help me.how can i get the same time format

**output2:  2022-07-20 19:01:36.783904+00:00,  6120c464-085e-11ed-80b2-0242ac120002**

Comment: FYI, it is the same time so I'm not sure what the issue is?

Comment: Could it be due to timezone?

Comment: are you referring to the format or the time-zone ?  if it is the time-zone, then yes.

Comment: Yes I'm a newbie ..I'm referring to the timezone and also the format ..I want the exact thing as it is shows in the db...sorry for if I can't make you understand very well

Answer (score 0):

if you are asking about formating `datetime`, then you can do this with the `strftime()` function to generate your specific desired format:

```py
import datetime

process_date_time = str(datetime.datetime.now())
last_run_time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')


print(process_date_time)
print(last_run_time)
```

the results will look like this (or whatever format you choose):

```
2022-07-31 08:40:45.652088
2022-07-31 08:40:45
```

here are the options:
https://strftime.org/